# Github Issue: credential-osxkeychain

Tags: git, github

I get asked for my git user and password everytime I try push something. I recently added the credential-osxkeychain as recommended on the setup page and upgraded my git version to 1.8.

Whatever happened with the helper install, something got screwed up. I can still push but any idea what's wrong? and how I can fix?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. If you are cloning/pushing/pulling using the SSH URL, you should not be prompted for a password as the public/private keys you've set up should be used. You will be prompted if you are using the HTTPS URL.

Comment: I think the message for the first error should be clear enough: You can't SSH into Github. Remove that from the question since it has nothing to do with the other problem.

Comment: How do i change the push url? In my git .config file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question but from the comments I see you want to change your push url. You can always recreate your remote by using

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

Comment: What's unclear about the question? After I installed the credential helper, my remote url somehow got changed to https url as opposed to the ssh url and now I have to authenticate with every push. I tried your suggestion with 'git remote add <name> <url>' with name being the name of the repository but got told that it already exists? Do I need to remove the variable first?